# How can I display Git Extensions menu on Toolbar in Vs 2009?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I installed Git Extensions, the commands can be listed by menu , you can see Image 1.

Can I display these command on a toolbar? so I can launch a command of Git quickly!

**Image 1**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not see a way to add directly those [Git Extensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/) commands, but:

You can [add to your toolbar a button for an external command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/213278/6309).

That means you can add an [external command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools?view=vs-2019) calling Git (since GitExtensions uses Git For windows)